# Page loads only half of the page

Tags: php, jquery, loops, load

I don't really know what happened here but the php code is somewhat faulty. This page has 5 webinars in it: http://veteducation.com.au/webinar/

The problem is only 1 webinar is shown on the first time load but when you refresh it, the other 4 webinar shows up.

Why is my page loading 1 webinar only on first time load and 4 webinar when refreshed? I want to see the 5 webinar on the first time load.

Please help me with this.

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'webinars', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'posts_per_page'=>-1 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>
                <?php include( TEMPLATEPATH."/"."includes/class.common.php" );
                $classObj = new Common_Class(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I loaded it up in IE, Chrome, and Opera but they all showed all 5.  It sounds like your browser is aggressively caching a version with 1 webinar loaded and then actually loading the page when you press refresh.

Try clearing your browser cache or load it in a fresh browser (Chrome's incognito mode is great for this).

Comment: ditto, could even be isp caching.

Comment: Hello Inca. Thank you for the reply. I've asked friends from Australia, UK and Philippines to load it and they are only seeing 1 webinar at first time load. However, when they refresh it 5 webinars shows up. I guess this is not just a browser issue as I always clear my browser cache too.